# Calculating the amount of the previous transaction of a different category for each transaction in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, data-manipulation

I have a DataFrame `df` that contains transactions from customers. Each row in the DataFrame represents a transaction and has the following columns:

- `KEY_ID`: the ID of the customer who made the transaction.
- `TYPE`: the type of transaction, which can be of two categories.
- `DATE`: the date the transaction was made.
- `AMOUNT`: the amount of the transaction.

I need to add a new column to the DataFrame that contains the amount of the previous transaction of the opposite category for each transaction. That is, for each transaction of a certain type, I want to know how much was the amount of the last transaction of a different type that the same customer made before the date of the current transaction.

First I sorted the `df` by `KEY_ID` and `DATE`:

```
df= df.sort_values(by=['KEY_ID', 'FECHA'])
```

Then tried to create a function that creates a subset called `previous_requests`

```
def find_previous_request(row):
    # Get previous requests of the opposite type
    previous_requests = df[
        (df['KEY_ID'] == row['KEY_ID']) &
        (df['TYPE'] != row['TYPE']) &
        (df['DATE'] < row['DATE'])
    ]
    
    # If there are previous requests, return the amount of the most recent one
    if not previous_requests.empty:
        return previous_requests.iloc[-1]['AMOUNT']
    
    # If there are no previous requests, return NaN
    return np.nan
```

**The kernel crashes when I apply the function.**

Also tried the following code:

```
df['prev_amount'] = df.groupby(['KEY_ID', 'TYPE'])['AMOUNT'].shift().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

**EDIT:**

Input:

| KEY_ID | TYPE | AMOUNT | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Motor | 5000 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | Tool | 3000 | 2020-02-01 |
| 1 | Tool | 7000 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2 | Tool | 2000 | 2020-01-15 |
| 2 | Motor | 6000 | 2020-02-15 |
| 2 | Tool | 4000 | 2020-03-15 |

Expected Output:

| KEY_ID | TYPE | AMOUNT | DATE | PREV_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Motor | 5000 | 2020-01-01 | NaN |
| 1 | Tool | 3000 | 2020-02-01 | 5000 |
| 1 | Tool | 7000 | 2020-03-01 | 5000 |
| 2 | Tool | 2000 | 2020-01-15 | NaN |
| 2 | Motor | 6000 | 2020-02-15 | 2000 |
| 2 | Tool | 4000 | 2020-03-15 | 6000 |

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your sample data, I guess @Michael Cao has pointed out 99% of the answer, his answer misses the KEY_ID, since you don't want to have the amounts of the KEY_ID 1 in KEY_ID 2:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['KEY_ID'])

for name, group in grouped:
    last_motor = None
    last_tool = None
    for ind, row in group.sort_values(['KEY_ID', 'DATE']).iterrows():
        if row.TYPE == 'Motor':
            df.loc[ind, 'PREV_AMOUNT'] = last_tool
            last_motor = row.AMOUNT
        if row.TYPE == 'Tool':
            df.loc[ind, 'PREV_AMOUNT'] = last_motor
            last_tool = row.AMOUNT
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the rows sorted by date and keep track of the last transaction so far and update as you go down:

```
last_motor = None
last_tool = None

for ind, row in df.sort_values('DATE').iterrows():
    if row.TYPE == 'Motor':
        df.loc[ind, 'PREV_AMOUNT'] = last_tool
        last_motor = row.AMOUNT
    if row.TYPE == 'Tool':
        df.loc[ind, 'PREV_AMOUNT'] = last_motor
        last_tool = row.AMOUNT
```

As pointed out by @Ali Massoud, I missed matching the `KEY_ID`, please refer to his answer as it is complete.